# How to uniformly implement two-way conversion without code repetition?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures

I have two big C structures used in a C legacy code, and I need to convert from one to another, and the other way around. Something like this :

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a;
    float b;
};
struct B {
    char a;
    int b;
};

struct C {
    A a;
    B b;
};

struct D {
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
};

void CtoD( const C& c, D &d ) {
    d.a = c.a.a;
    d.b = c.b.a;
    d.c = c.a.b;
}
void DtoC( const D &d, C& c ) {
    c.a.a = d.a;
    c.b.a = d.b;
    c.a.b = d.c;
}

int main()
{
    C c = { { 1, 3.3f }, { 'a', 4 } };
    D d = { 1, 'b', 5.5f };

#if 0
    CtoD( c, d );
#else
    DtoC( d, c );
#endif

    std::cout<<"C="<<c.a.a<<" "<<c.a.b<<" "<<c.b.a<<" "<<c.b.b<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"D="<<d.a<<" "<<d.b<<" "<<d.c<<std::endl;
}
```

Functions `CtoD` and `DtoC` are doing the same thing, but in opposite direction. Changing one structure requires changing both of them.

To minimize possibility of an error, and to avoid repetition, I would like to implement some kind of mapping, where I define the connections only once, and then I copy one value to another. This way, only one change is needed if a structure changes.

So, the question is : how to do it? Is there perhaps a design pattern I could use?

---

My real structures have hundreds of fields. The above is just simplified example.

Comment: This connection pattern would really look like the signal/slot pattern of QT, but it works because every object inherits from a common QObject ancestor. Doing this for arbitrary types is going to be horribly tedious, and in the end not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get naughty...

```
struct rightwards_t {} rightwards;
struct leftwards_t {} leftwards;

template<typename Left, typename Right>
inline void map_field(Left& left, const Right& right, leftwards_t) {
    left = right;
}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
inline void map_field(const Left& left, Right& right, rightwards_t) {
    right = left;
}

template<typename Direction>
void convert(C& c, D& d, Direction direction) {
    map_field(c.a.a, d.a, direction);
    map_field(c.b.a, d.b, direction);
    map_field(c.a.b, d.c, direction);
}

// Usage
C c;
D d;
convert(c, d, leftwards); // Converts d into c
convert(c, d, rightwards); // Converts c into d
```

Really don't know if it works (no compiler at hand), but I wanted to write it. If anyone can help me make it correct, please do.

Comment: Although it is not finished, I see how to modify my example.

Answer (score 2):

In your literal example, I don't think it's worth the hassle. Just write tests so that you ensure your conversions work well.

In your real code, if your structs have "hundreds of fields", your structs may be badly designed. Maybe they should be composed of smaller objects. I've never designed anything which required hunderds of fields in exactly the same struct object - instead, these fields allowed some kind of classification so that they could be treated in smaller bunches.

Since your code is *legacy* and you don't want to rewrite it, just write tests for your conversions functions, as I said above for the example.

Well tested code is no longer *legacy* code. Legacy code is basically code for which you don't have automated tests.

**If rewriting it is not an option, testing it is a must.**

About the cost of testing it "both ways", Idan Arye's [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377612/how-to-uniformly-implement-two-way-conversion-without-code-repetition/19377685?noredirect=1#comment28717291_19377685) says everything:

> Since the conversion is symmetric, testing it both ways is not that
>   much more work than testing it one way. All you need to do is init two
>   structs - `C c` and `D d` - and set them to be the converted versions of
>   each other. Then you just have to check that `CtoD(c)==d` and
>   `DtoC(d)==c` (or use comparison functions if you happen to have them
>   defined). The big work here is initializing `c` and `d` - but you would
>   have to do that anyways if you wanted to test one way conversion, so
>   adding the test for the other way is very cheap.

Comment: The term "Legacy code" usually means "Badly written\designed code that needed to be extended\modified\fixed but we can't rewrite it from scratch".

Comment: @IdanArye I updated my answer to take into account that this is _legacy_ code.

Comment: I was actually referring to the structs, which can't be refactored because they are "legacy". Even with proper unittests, refactoring types(and all the code that uses them) might be too much work to be approved...

Comment: @IdanArye My update was refering to the alternative without refactoring the structs. Just unit test your conversion functions. If it is not approved, then don't do it.

Comment: The real structure has several huge WTFs, therefore I wouldn't call it well designed. Rewriting it at the moment is not an option. And I would like to avoid having to test conversion both way

Comment: @BЈовић If rewriting it is not an option, testing it is a must. You shouldn't _want_ to avoid testing it.

Comment: @BЈовић Since the conversion is symmetric, testing it both ways is not that much more work than testing it one way. All you need to do is init two structs - `C c` and `D d` - and set them to be the converted versions of each other. Then you just have to check that `CtoD(c)==d` and `DtoC(d)==c`(or use comparison functions if you happen to have them defined). The big work here is initializing `c` and `d` - but you would have to do that anyways if you wanted to test one way conversion, so adding the test for the other way is very cheap.

Comment: @IdanArye Your comment adds relevant information, so I added it to the answer.

Comment: Forgot to say : the structure represents the HW memory map of a relatively complex device. That is why it has hundreds of fields.

Comment: @BЈовић It should be modularized, or at least categorized. No real world field escapes the need for modularity when it is translated to code.

Comment: It is modularized in a way that it has grouped fields into substructures. Unfortunately, I can not change one structure (the one that is a mess).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a container of hundreds of `std::pair`s of references to the sub-objects involved.  With a references, you can both read and write, so reading from the left-object and writing to the right-object converts one-way.  The opposite convert the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Pick your favorite scripting language(if you don't have one yet I recommend Ruby) and write a small script that generate the conversion functions for you(both source and header files).

Unless you pick a lame scripting language, you can even represent the connections directly in the language, when calling the functions that generate the converters. For example, in Ruby after defining `generate_converters` you could write:

```
generate_converters :C,:D do
    convert 'a.a','a'
    convert 'b.a','b'
    convert 'a.b','c'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel, not worth the hassle, but you could write a little app that generates the code for you. You feed the app with description of two structs, and bindings between struct members, and the app generates the C code that is then compiled as usual.

Another alternative is to fiddle with [pointers to members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx), but that could consume even more developer's time, so is even less worth the hassle than the first option.

Comment: It is not possible to create pointer to member variable of a member variable. In the above example, it is not possible to create pointer to member variable `c.a.b`. You can create pointer to member variable `c.a`. Or, if you can show in code what you meant

Comment: @BЈовић as stated, it's too much of a hassle. Be practical, say 'no' to pointers to members...

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to do this. And I came out with next solution :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

struct A {
    int a;
    float b;
};
struct B {
    char a;
    int b;
};

struct C {
    A a;
    B b;
};

struct D {
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
};

template< typename T1, typename T2 >
struct DataField
{
    static inline void Update( const T1 & src, T2 & dst ) { dst = src; }
    static inline void Update( T1 & dst, const T2 & src ) { dst = src; }
};
template<>
struct DataField< const char*, char* >
{
    static inline void Update( const char* src, char* dst ) { strcpy( dst, src ); }
};
template<>
struct DataField< char*, const char* >
{
    static inline void Update( char* dst, const char* src ) { strcpy( dst, src ); }
};
template< typename T1, typename T2, int N  >
struct DataField< T1[N], T2[N] >
{
    static inline void Update( const T1 (&src)[N], T2 (&dst)[N] ) { std::copy_n( src, N, dst ); }
    static inline void Update( T1 (&dst)[N], const T1 (&src)[N] ) { std::copy_n( src, N, dst ); }
};

template< typename T1, typename T2 >
void UpdateDataField( T1 & src, T2 & dst )
{
    DataField< T1, T2 >::Update( src, dst );
}


template< typename T1, typename T2 >
void UpdateMappedDataFields( T1 & src, T2 & dst )
{
    UpdateDataField( src.a.a,  dst.a );
    UpdateDataField( src.a.b,  dst.c );

    UpdateDataField( src.b.a,  dst.b );
}

void CtoD( const C& c, D &d ) {
    UpdateMappedDataFields( c, d );
}
void DtoC( const D &d, C& c ) {
    UpdateMappedDataFields( c, d );
}

int main()
{
    C c = { { 1, 3.3f }, { 'a', 4 } };
    D d = { 1, 'b', 5.5f };

#if 0
    CtoD( c, d );
#else
    DtoC( d, c );
#endif

    std::cout<<"C="<<c.a.a<<" "<<c.a.b<<" "<<c.b.a<<" "<<c.b.b<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"D="<<d.a<<" "<<d.b<<" "<<d.c<<std::endl;
}
```

All data fields mapping is done in the `UpdateMappedDataFields` function, and only there.

What I don't like is that the function `UpdateMappedDataFields` is a template, and the way it is implemented, it prevents autocomplete when using IDEs, since the types are not known.

However, I would still like to hear if there is a better way.

Comment: Please look at my response. I'm using direction tags for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Idan and Dialecticus proposed, you can also just use your editor's search and replace function: 
E.g. write `CtoD` manually, copy the body to `DtoC` and - in eclipse - use

```
 Find:    ^(.*)=(.*);  
 Replace: $2=$1;
```

in order to automatically swap the left and right side of each assignment in the body of `DtoC`.

Whether or not this is preferable to the usage of more or less complex c++ constructs depends on your specific code and requirements. In my opinion, the code is easier to read and maintain this way, but of course nothing enforces coherency between `CtoD` and `DtoC` after future changes (I'd mention the procedure in a code comment).